# Get consecutive values based on value being passed in

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking for a way to pass in a value and get 3 values out of it.  Meaning if I pass in the value 0, the print out will be 0 1 2. Thus this is actual value passed in plus the next 2 consecutive numbers.

But it's not just the about consecutive numbers. For example, if I pass in 1, I am NOT expecting 1 2 3. Instead it should be as follows.

- `0` passed in so print `0 1 2`.
- Now passing in `1`. `0 1 2` already done with above call.
  Thus passing in `1` will print `3 4 5`.
- Now passing in `2`. `0 1 2 3 4 5` already done with above calls.
  Thus passing `2` will output `6 7 8` and so on.

The following code works as intended but kinda silly to be writing it out this way plus the value being passed in is determined by external factors and I won't know it beforehand.

But if the value passed in is example 3, the algorithm should calculate that

3 multiples of 3 has passed (index 0 - 8).

Thus passing in 3 would mean print 9, 10, 11.

The following code does whats explained above. But is not scalable thus looking for some sort of looping algorithm.

```
class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app = new App();
        app.printIndex(0); // idea is to print the index being passed in and the next 2 numbers, so 0 1 2
        app.printIndex(1); // 3 4 5
        app.printIndex(2); // 6 7 8
        app.printIndex(3); // 9 10 11
    }

    int getIndex(int i) {
        if(i == 0) return i;

        if(i == 1) return 3;

        if(i == 2) return 6;

        if(i == 3) return 9;

        return 0;
    }

    void printIndex(int i) {

        System.out.println(getIndex(i));
        System.out.println(getIndex(i) + 1);
        System.out.println(getIndex(i) + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just `return i*3`

Comment: Try `System.out.println(i*3 + ", " + (i*3  + 1) + ", " + (i*3 + 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int getIndex(int i) {
    return i*3;
}
```

your getIndex method needs to just return i*3 to get every 3rd number. Your program should work if you just replace this. You could even leave out the `getIndex()` method entirely if you edit your `printIndex()` method to

```
void printIndex(int i) {
    System.out.println(i*3+"");
    System.out.println(i*3 + 1);
    System.out.println(i*3 + 2);
}
```

Comment: Feeling rather silly now. Makes sense. Need an exception for the value 0 but otherwise, this should work. Thanks.

Comment: sure thing, what do you mean exception for the value 0?

Comment: Scarcth that, no exception needed.